# Incorrect Display on Linux (+HiDPI)

Tags: linux, display

I have Linux on a HiDPI laptop, and after first installing Mathematica, the default font size is far too small:

[image: Default settings on Mathematica]

After searching for a few solutions, this can be fixed by either changing the magnification to 200% (in `Notebook Options -> Display Options -> Magnification`), or alternatively doubling the screen resolution in `Formatting Options -> Font Options -> FontProperties -> ScreenResolution`.  (They seem, as far as I can tell, equivalent?)

Anyway, whichever method I end up choosing, it ends up magnifying another issue:  the horizontal width of elements is small than the display width of these elements:

[image: incorrect horizontal width]

As you can see, some elements start running into each other, or alternatively get cropped by other elements.  This issue is already present (though to a lesser extent) in the non-magnified display (you can see that 't' of `Dataset` is cropped).

In this particular picture, it is merely an inconvenience, but I am regularly finding a few instances where it is much more severely impacting the legibility of the output.  For example:

[image: really bad horizontal spacing]

Has anyone else experienced this issue?  And how can I fix it, or at least improve legibility?

Comment: Have you reported this issue to `support@wolfram.com`? If not, you should do it.

Comment: I did not originally, but I have contacted them now.  They may answer here, or if they answer by email, I shall post their response here.

Comment: I don't see the clipping and collisions when using Magnification.  Are you certain that you do, and not only when using `FontProperties -> ScreenResolution`?  The latter only affects fonts, if I recall correctly, therefore the bounding areas do not increase and clipping can occur.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the first picture already shows some of the clipping and collisions, and that screenshot is with the default settings (that is, after removing `~/.mathematica` completely).  I have tried both ways of magnifying, and both seem equivalent in that they both produce clipping.

Comment: Any updates on this? Would be very happy if this was improved in version 11.

Comment: Mathematica 11 still has this issue.  I have found that it helps if you change the default Mathematica font to something else; so perhaps it is a font issue?  (I recommend using Inconsolata-g for the monospace font, and Roboto for text)